# For loop in flask not visible in html page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm actually looking to print a for loop in flask templates, I used different methods but nothing appears on the html page, the python code is working properly, I just don't know how to implement it with jinja.

Views.py

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def results():

    keyword = {'keyword': request.args.get('keyword')} # First Method
    keyword = request.form['keyword'] # Second Method

    num_tweets=5

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=str(keyword)+
        " -filter:retweets",
        result_type='recent',
        lang="en").items(num_tweets):
        clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", tweet.text)
        result = cool.api(clean)
    return render_template('pages/results.html')
```

Results.html

```
<body>
<div>

{{ result }}
{{ clean }}

</div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing any data to  be rendered.

```
results = list() 
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=str(keyword)+
    " -filter:retweets",
    result_type='recent',
    lang="en").items(num_tweets):
        clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", tweet.text)
        result = cool.api(clean)
        results.append((result, clean)) 
return render_template('pages/results.html', results=results)
```

You also will need to implement a loop in Jinja2

```
{% for result in results %} 
{{ result[0] }}
{{ result[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

But none of this makes any sense.

You have a loop through a series of tweets. Inside that loop, you repeatedly overwrite the `result` and `clean` variables with a value. So, by the end of the loop, you just get the final variable.

Of course, all that makes no difference anyway because you don't even send those variables to the template to be rendered, so of course the template is blank.

You need to accumulate the values in a list. Then, you need to send the list to the template. Finally, you need to iterate through the list in the template.

```
results = []
for tweet in ...:
    clean = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", tweet.text)
    result = cool.api(clean)
    results.append((clean, result))
 return render_template('pages/results.html', results=results)
```

...

```
{% for clean, result in results %}
    {{ clean }}
    {{ result }}
 {% endfor %}
```